# Django is hashing my passwords different when creating a User vs trying to authenticate a user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm having trouble getting authentication to work and I found that the problem is my when I create a user their password is hashed in a different style than PBKDF2. Instead the passwords are always in a format like this: !iak7ijJTzsXRgsbwqtQBtXCZeU3Ccd96k2PpOCRa .

However, when I'm working in my views `make_password` and `check_password` are using PBKDF2.

Model:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_super_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")

        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    
    email=models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='Email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
    )

    password=models.CharField(
        max_length=255, 
        verbose_name='password'
    )

    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I suspect the issue is coming from my custom Model, but it's identical to one I wrote for another app that had no issues.

Register View:

```
class CreateUser(APIView):
    serializer_class = CreateUserSerializer
    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            email = serializer.data.get('email')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')

            userObj = User.objects.create_user(email=email, password=password)
            userObj.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Login View:

```
class LogIn(APIView):
    serializer_class = LogInSerializer
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            email = serializer.data.get('email')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')

            tObj = User.objects.get(email=email)
            hashed_pwd = make_password("123456")
            print(hashed_pwd)
            print(tObj.password)

            print(tObj.check_password(password))
            

            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            print(user)

            if user is not None:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` at the start of the password value has a special meaning in Django - it means that an [unusable password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password) has been set for the user - the rest of the value is just a random string that will never be successfully validated.

So the question is *why* is an unusable password being set? There are two possibilities I can see from your code:

1. `UserManager.create_super_user` doesn't set the user's password at all - if you are using this to create users, then no password will be set for them.
2. If you're using the `CreateUserSerializer`, then it may be that the value of `password` is `None` - we would need to see the serializer definition to confirm whether a null value would be considered valid. I think this is the most likely issue. Passing `None` to `create_user` will cause `set_password` to set an unusable password. You then need to investigate why an empty value is being passed to the serializer.

Comment: The unusable password clears up so much. I thought it was a hashing issues. I'll take a look at the serializer, as I don't think it's option 1 because I haven't used create_super_user. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was what solarissmoke proposed with the CreateUserSerializer. I had my password set to write only which wasn't letting my view to get to password, instead it was returning None.

I changed my view from this:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {'write_only': True}
        }
```

To this (corrected version):

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```